# Add to the second position of a Fluid array

Tags: typo3, fluid

Currently I have this code that wraps every 2 items with `<li></li>`

```
<f:for each="{modules}" as="module" iteration="loop">
            <f:cycle values="{0: 1, 1: 0}" as="header">
                <li>
            </f:cycle>
            ...stuff here...
            <f:cycle values="{0: 0, 1: 1}" as="footer">
                </li>
            </f:cycle>
      </f:for>
```

Lets say {modules} = [A,B,C,D] and output is something like this:

```
<li>AB</li>
<li>CD</li>
```

What I need to do is add custom html to the second position. So my desired output is:

```
<li>AX</li>
<li>BC</li>
<li>D</li>
```

How can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your updated question I would say, you may want to solve this issue with your own Helper class before adding modules to the View through the Controller.

It is however possible to build it simple in the template:

Here is the documentation about the [for ViewHelper](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/For.html#example-with-iterator-information).

For simplicity I would do the following:

```
<f:for each="{modules}" as="module" iteration="loop">

            <f:if condition="{loop.isFirst}">
              <f:then>
                <li>
                 {module}
                 ##extra_code##
                </li>
              </f:then>
              <f:else>
                  <f:if condition="{loop.isEven}">
                     <li>
                  </f:if>
                    ...stuff here...
                  <f:if condition="{loop.isOdd} || {loop.isLast}">
                    </li>
                  </f:if>                  
            </f:else>
            </f:if>

      </f:for>
```

*Note: The first element will be "odd" because isOdd takes the current interation (based on "cycle"), which starts with 1.*

For the first element there is your own block. You can take the first module and write your own code. It will run only once.

From the second element to the last it will use the 2 element in one li logic. Here is only one interesting thing, that we need take isOdd OR isLast to always close the last li, even if you have an even number of elements.

Comment: I didn't explain myself well enough, updated question.

Comment: It is a more tricky but after you get isEven / isOdd / isFirst / isLast it easy to puzzle it together.

Comment: This works except for the last `<f:if condition="{loop.isOdd} || {loop.isLast}">` which is adding a `</li>` for every module?

Comment: I removed the `||` and used nested if's for that last one and that works for some reason...

Comment: @user500665: Which TYPO3 do you use? Based on the documentation it should work with > TYPO3 8.0. 
https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/ExtbaseGuide/Fluid/ViewHelper/If.html

Comment: That must be it, I think I'm on 7.6. Thank you. I'll have to keep that in mind.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this like below.

```
<f:for each="{modules}" as="module" iteration="iteration">
    <f:if condition="{iteration.isFirst}">
        <f:then>
            <li>
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <f:if condition="{iteration.index}%2">
                <f:then></f:then>
                <f:else><li></f:else>
            </f:if> 
           </f:else> 
        </f:if>
        <!--
            Here Your Content
         -->
        <f:if condition="{iteration.isLast}">
        <f:then>
            </li> 
        </f:then>
        <f:else>
            <f:if condition="{iteration.cycle}%2"> 
                <f:then></f:then>
                <f:else></li></f:else>
            </f:if>
        </f:else>
    </f:if> 
</f:for>
```

Comment: I didn't explain myself well enough, updated question.